# Background and border DIV doesn't fade out

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a problem with the FadeOut function. It fades out only the content and not the white background and border. I noticed if I REMOVE the `.product-div-container` which is outside of the while loop it WORKS.

But I need THAT DIV to put a box-shadow behind ALL products. I don't like the box shadow on every product individually because i have a fade-in/fade-out function on the product DIV when the quantity changes. And then you will see the ugly box shadow on top of another div.

So how can i fade out the `.whole-product-div` without removing the `.product-div-container`?

```js
$(".delete-product-cart").click(function() {
  $('.whole-product-div[data-id="' + $(this).data('id') + '"]').fadeOut(1300, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.product-div-container {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px grey;
}

.styling-cart {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='product-div-container' class='product-div-container'>
  <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='1'>
    <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='1'>Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please post a sample of the rendered HTML instead of the PHP `while` loop?

Comment: @disinfor The HTML is inside the PHP ECHO? What's the difference

Comment: @disinfor I thought it was important to show that there is also a while loop

Comment: Because we can't test it without the rendered HTML and you shouldn't expect people helping to create the markup to do so.. The `while` loop isn't part of your issue. Your issue is the JavaScript and the elements. We just need an example with one of your divs inside of the container.

Comment: @disinfor Oke done thank you, do you know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
  $(".delete-product-cart").click(function(){
    $('.whole-product-div[data-id="'+id+'"]')
        .removeClass('whole-product-div')
        .fadeOut(1300, function(){ 
           $(this).remove();
         });
  });
```

To remove the box shadow immediately before fading it out

Comment: This has the same effect. The background doesn't fade out only the content.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7z2k193t/ I made a jsfiddle from another question and it has the same output as yours. The content fades out but not the product div that it deletes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated answer which give what I believe to be (closer to) the desired effect -- The CSS color background on .product-div-container is the only change required:

JS:

```
$(".delete-product-cart").click(function() {
  $('.whole-product-div[data-id="' + $(this).data('id') + '"]').fadeOut(1300, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.product-div-container {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px grey;
  min-height: 1px;
  background: yellow;
}

.styling-cart {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}

.styling-cart:nth-child(odd) {
  border-color: red;
}

html {background:yellow;}
```

HTML:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='product-div-container' class='product-div-container'>
  <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='1'>
    <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='1'>Delete</a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='2'>
    <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='2'>Delete</a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='3'>
    <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='3'>Delete</a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='4'>
    <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='4'>Delete</a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='5'>
    <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='5'>Delete</a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='6'>
    <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='6'>Delete</a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='7'>
    <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='7'>Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

A link to the forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/26a8hd7k/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this deletes all products

Comment: I mean this Fades out every product

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7z2k193t/ I made a jsfiddle from another question and it has the same output as yours. The content fades out but not the product div that it deletes.

Comment: Updated answer using .fadeOut method.

Comment: Hey thanks i will check it tomorrow. Gonna sleep, thanks for ur time and effort. I will let you know

Comment: I have difficulties now to find the div parent. Because between delete class and `whole-product-div` there are 20 other classes.

Comment: I tried `$(this).parents('.whole-product-div').addClass('transparent');` But that fades out the content and leaves the div product div empty

Comment: I see now what you did you made both background yellow then you will not see that it doesn't fade out the div. And the div was full width so you couldn't see the shadow. That's why it seemed that your code works. But it doesn't. I can still see the shadow around the div when clicking DELETE. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

This will fade out each of the divs when you click on it's `delete` button and leaves the container with the drop shadow in place.

You can use the `data` attribute of the button to target its parent. I commented the jQuery

```js
$(".delete-product-cart").click(function() {
  // Here we use $(this) to reference the a tag's data attribute so it targets its parent div.
  $('.whole-product-div[data-id="' + $(this).data('id') + '"]').fadeOut(1300, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: purple !important;
}

.product-div-container {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px grey;
}

.styling-cart {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  background: yellow;
}

.styling-cart:nth-child(odd) {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='product-div-container' class='product-div-container'>
    <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='1'>
      <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='1'>Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='2'>
      <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='2'>Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='3'>
      <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='3'>Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='4'>
      <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='4'>Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='5'>
      <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='5'>Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='6'>
      <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='6'>Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12 styling-cart whole-product-div' data-id='7'>
      <a class='delete-product-cart' data-id='7'>Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I put your code in a JSFIDDLE. Because i couldn't believe this is the 3th answer and it has the same output. https://jsfiddle.net/7z2k193t/ As you can see in the JSFIDDLE the content FADES out but then after the div removes. I want the product div to fade out with background and everything.

Comment: Oh, so you basically don't want the background of the parent div to appear for that split second after the child element is removed? Because what you are seeing isn't the `whole-product-div` background, it's the `product-container-div` before it readjusts its size after the child element is removed from the DOM.

Comment: I dont understand. Because i am fading out the product and the container doesn’t have styling. Can this be fixed or is there another way to put box shadow? And i dont like box shadow on every seperate product. Because a quantity click will fade out and fade in for a sec and then the shadow from another product div will show

Comment: Here's what is happening: You are fading out the product (`.whole-product-div`), however, fading is only changing the opacity of that element. It's size is still technically there until you have the `.remove()` function. The container (`product-container-div`) does have styling - `box-shadow`. Without some major JS rewriting and calculations to determine element height, this won't work. You're honestly better off finding a way to add a box shadow to each `whole-product-div` and adjust it on qty click - which we don't have code for. Add that and we might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, i got it now. I made a JSFIDDLE with a quantity button effect. So when you remove the container div and put the box shadow inside the product-div. You will see the shadows overlapping on other products. And if something is fixed, i also don't want to see the box shadow overlapping other product-divs when clicking the quantity button. Let me know if you can make it work. I appreciate your explanation, your time and your answers. https://jsfiddle.net/7zptwcbv/1/